# Using UUID PK or FK in Firebird with Jooq

Tags: java, firebird, jooq, firebird-3.0

I have a table in Firebird with a PK column

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  ID CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

OCTETS encoding are treated as bytes.

I create a converter

```
public class UUIDConverter implements Converter<byte[], UUID>{

    @Override
    public Class<byte[]> fromType() {
        return byte[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<UUID> toType() {
        return UUID.class;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID from(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) return null;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        long high = bb.getLong();
        long low = bb.getLong();
        return new UUID(high, low);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] to(UUID uuid) {
        if (uuid == null) return null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Then I configured the converter in my pom (I'm using maven to generate the source)

```
<customTypes>
    <customType>
        <name>UUID</name>
        <converter>com.vas.database.UUIDConverter</converter>
    </customType>
</customTypes>
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>VARBINARY</name>
        <expressions>ID|ID_.*</expressions>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Although the code is generated, it is not what I expect.

```
public final TableField<TestRecord, byte[]> ID = createField("ID", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARBINARY.nullable(false), this, "");
```

This is what I would like it to be generated (I made the changes by hand and everything works wonderfully).

```
public final TableField<TestRecord, UUID> ID = createField("ID", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARBINARY.nullable(false), this, "", new UUIDConverter());
```

How do I make it work?
(By the way, I'm using Firebird 3.0, Jooq 3.10.1 and Jaybird 2.2.13)

Comment: _"it is not what I expect"_, could you be more specific about what exactly the problem is?

Comment: For example, what code does it generate, and why doesn't that work for you? BTW: Consider upgrading to Jaybird 3.0.2, it has better handling of `character set octets` (see [Character set OCTETS handled as JDBC (VAR)BINARY](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.2/release_notes.html#character-set-octets-handled-as-jdbc-varbinary). Also, `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` is a 'binary' type, not 'varbinary'.

Comment: Mark thanks for your fast response. I edited my question (trying to be clearer). Is Jaybir 3.0.2 ready for production?

Comment: Something else, VARBINARY is a data type from Jooq as you can see here 
 rg.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARBINARY) and It is not a Jaybird data type.

Comment: Jaybird 3.0.2 is a released version, so yes, it is ready for production. But consult the release notes, and test it, because there are a number of breaking changes compared to 2.2.x. In any case `SQLDataType.BINARY` is a closer match to the intent of `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` than varbinary. Not sure if it matters for this problem though.

Comment: Did you try forced type UUID instead of VARBINARY (or BINARY)?

Comment: Mark thanks for all your comments. I will follow all your advice and I'll see what happens. I forced VARBINARY

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I forced to UUID,  the data type I got is org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.UUID instead of  org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BINARY and After that I got I compilation error. If there also a chance to force Jooq BINARY data type? That will solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't done much with this part of jOOQ, I would need to try a few things to see what works. Maybe Lukas sees this question before that time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to explain here:

#### 1. Your config is wrong

In your current configuration, only this part applies to the code generator, rewriting your `CHAR` data type to `VARBINARY` using the [data type rewriting](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/) feature:

```xml
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>VARBINARY</name>
        <expressions>ID|ID_.*</expressions>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

The custom type for the `UUID` type is never applied because you don't force any column to the UUID type. (btw, you shouldn't name your custom type `UUID`, because that conflicts with [`SQLDataType.UUID`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html#UUID))

#### 2. You cannot rewrite a type twice

The current version of jOOQ 3.10 doesn't allow you to rewrite a type twice, i.e. from `CHAR` to `VARBINARY` and then from `VARBINARY` to your user-defined type. This is a limitation which might be fixed in a future version.

But right now, you have to implement this in one go.

By default, jOOQ would read / write `CHAR` types using `java.lang.String` and JDBC's corresponding `PreparedStatement.setString()` and `ResultSet.getString()` methods, regardless of any encoding / collation / etc. This is probably not what you want. Instead, you should not implement a `Converter` but a `Binding` as documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings

It allows you to "bind" your custom data type directly to JDBC, bypassing jOOQ's internal `DefaultBinding` semantics (which would call `setString()` and `getString()`)