# JOOQ generates CHAR OCTETS columns as CHAR instead of BINARY

Tags: firebird, jooq, jaybird

My problem very close the one mentioned in [Using UUID PK or FK in Firebird with Jooq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313967/using-uuid-pk-or-fk-in-firebird-with-jooq)

Setup:
Jaybird 3.0.5, Firebird 2.5.7, jOOQ 3.11.7, JDK 1.8

My PK and FK fields like

```
ID CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL
```

and

```
TABLE_ID CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS
```

and I want to use UUID as java data type in generated classes

I use JDBC connection in configuration like

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:c:/DBS/DB.FDB?octetsAsBytes=true</url>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <key>user</key>
            <value>SYSDBA</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>password</key>
            <value>masterkey</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</jdbc>
```

I have setup forcedType in generator like

```
<forcedType>
    <userType>java.util.UUID</userType>
    <binding>com.ekser.nakkash.icdv.converters.jooq.ByteArray2UUIDBinding</binding>
    <expression>.*ID$</expression>
    <types>CHAR\(16\)</types>
    <nullability>ALL</nullability>
</forcedType>
```

and I have class

```
class ByteArray2UUIDBinding implements Binding<byte[], UUID>
```

Now the problem

jOOQ generates

```
public final TableField<MyTableRecord, UUID> ID = createField("ID", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.CHAR(16).nullable(false), this, "", new ByteArray2UUIDBinding());
```

problem is `SQLDataType.CHAR(16)`, it should be `SQLDataType.BINARY(16)`.

jOOQ translate my `char(16) octets` fields as string (`char(16)`), it does not respect `octetsAsBytes=true`.

I have tried to put it to properties in `<jdbc>` like

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:c:/DBS/DB.FDB</url>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <key>user</key>
            <value>SYSDBA</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>password</key>
            <value>masterkey</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>octetsAsBytes</key>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</jdbc>
```

With the same result.

What is wrong?
I am considering running search&replace for keyword `CHAR(16)` -> `BINARY(16)` in generated classes for now, which is not 'stylish'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `octetsAsBytes` does nothing in Jaybird 3, see [Character set OCTETS handled as JDBC (VAR)BINARY](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/release_notes.html#character-set-octets-handled-as-jdbc-varbinary) in the Jaybird 3 release notes. Jaybird 3 always behaves as `octetsAsBytes=true` in previous versions with some further improvements.

In other words, this is not related to that setting at all, but is instead a result of how jOOQ generates this.

jOOQ does its own metadata introspection by directly querying the Firebird metadata tables and mapping the Firebird type codes to jOOQ SQL types (see [FirebirdTableDefinition](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-meta/src/main/java/org/jooq/meta/firebird/FirebirdTableDefinition.java) and [FirebirdDatabase.FIELD_TYPE](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-meta/src/main/java/org/jooq/meta/firebird/FirebirdDatabase.java#L322)). It directly maps Firebird type '15' to `CHAR`, without further considering subtypes (== character sets for this type).

In other words, you'll need to file an improvement ticket with jOOQ if you want to get this mapped to `BINARY` instead (although it's unclear to me why this is really a problem for you).

Comment: thanks for rapid answer. I know actetsAsBytes was ment for latest versions of Jaybird2, just you know .... may it would work... :) I suppose you are right about jOOQ code generation logic. Anyway I mark this answer as correct enough :)